# xfsretsore from a zipped image to a unmouted partition

Tags: restore, xfs

I have a zipped image which I am restoring to a unmounted partition:

```
gunzip -c /mnt/sda3/backup.gz | xfsrestore - /dev/sda7
```

I get a error:

```
xfsrestore: ERROR: specified destination /dev/sda7 is not a directory
xfsrestore: usage: xfsrestore [ -a <alt. workspace dir> ... ]
                          [ -b <blocksize> ]
                          [ -c <media change alert program
```

Is there a way to use xfsrestore to a unmounted partition.

My xfsdump command is:

```
xfsdump -l 0 - /dev/sda6 | gzip -c > /mnt/sda3/backup.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [xfsrestore(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfsrestore) man page, there is no way to restore without mounting the partition.

You will have to mount it and restore to the mountpoint.

> xfsrestore populates the specified destination directory, dest, with the files contained in the dump media